# Setting a reminder with Slack API

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm having trouble using the `reminder` method to set a reminder using the Slack API.

https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add

I want to set a reminder for various people in our workspace.  My understanding of the Slack API docs is that a `workspace` token is needed for permission, which I have created. See https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types#workspace

In POSTing the reminder request, I always get the error `{ ok: false, error: 'user_not_specified' }`. I have specified a user as part of the payload, as well as `text`, `time` and the bearer token.

Strange, because the docs say that `user` is optional. Removing the user from the payload results in the same error.

I'm getting the same error in both Postman and in a simple snippet using the Node Slack API library:

```
const { WebClient} = require('@slack/client');
const token = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN || require('./.config').SLACK_API_TOKEN;
const web = new WebClient(token);
web.reminders.add({text: 'clean up duty', time: 'in 1 minute', user: 'U0FKQ3N94'})
 .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: workspace tokens are still "beta". Have you tried with a normal user token?